# hints for low-carb wraps

Tags: low-carb

Lately two different bags from two different makers of low net carbohydrate wraps have arrived home with the entire mass stuck together. In both cases the expiration date had not passed. The first bag went right into the fridge when I got home and I opened it a week later. The second bag/brand I opened as soon as I got home.

They're not stored in the fridge at the grocery store. Could the recent hot weather be an issue? Or did I manage to pick from two bad lots lately? Any hints on getting the things apart?

I've emailed one manufacturer a few weeks ago, they have not bothered to respond yet.

Comment: I finally did get a weasel answer in a letter from the manufacture. Bottom line is I got two free coupons (which I promptly lost). I also tried a third brand, and that one tastes extra awful, though none stuck together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this happen with tortillas. Generally it's moisture or humidity that will cause them to stick. Try putting the entire stack in a low-temp oven (unwrapped and uncovered) for a few minutes to dry them out. You should be able to separate them easily. At that point you could either put them in separate bags, or stick a sheet of waxed paper/plastic wrap between each one and put them back in a single bag. If you're going to store them in the fridge, make sure that they're in an airtight container, as condensation can form in the bag and cause them to get gummy.

Comment: Thanks, I will give the oven a try if I buy them again. You would think at the price they are sold for they could afford a few wax sheets between layers already. I've carefully peeled the layers apart - lost a few - and then done the wax paper. That part at least I know works.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, and I have seen some that come with paper in between, but can't remember the brand right now. My answer is just a way to salvage the ones you already have.